# Can't move Dropbox to ~/Library/CloudStorage

Tags: macos, dropbox

I'm unable to complete the latest Dropbox update that changes the location of Dropbox on macOS to `~/Library/CloudStorage`.

[image]

Following the walkthrough that appears in the Dropbox app I get in an infinite loop where the files can't be moved ("right now").

[image]

FWIW, I can't move them there using the app's settings either, though I have no problem adding or changing files in the folder otherwise, and can even drag the Dropbox folder there in Finder (though that disconnects Dropbox).

How do I complete the update? Is anyone else having these issues.

(macOS 13.2.1 / MBA M2)

Comment: (Not a dropbox user).  Try Booting into Safe Mode so 3rd party apps load, then move the folder.  Your DropBox folder/files may be locked by other processes.  Rebooting should release them.

Comment: You might look at using [Maestral](https://maestral.app/) for Dropbox, rather than the mess the official client has become (not that it wasn't a mess before Apple changed the rules).

Comment: @Allan Wait — just adding an `m` to the filename resized it. Why didn't I know that? Cool!

Comment: @orome - you can add an “s”, “m”, or “l” for small, medium, or large, respectively. It’s a super convenient feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit Dropbox and then [delete the Dropbox cache folder](https://help.dropbox.com/delete-restore/cache-folder) (which is hidden by default), then launch Dropbox again. That should do it.

Comment: In my case "support" had me try every possible invasive fix (including resetting permissions, repairing the disk, disconnecting my Dropbox account on all machines, disabling my firewall, trying a different router, moving to a different network, etc. etc.) before revealing this as a potential (and kind of obvious) fix after about a week and a half of exchanges.